# Android: Overlay Window on Button Click

Tags: android, button, click, overlay

I want to open an overlay window when clicking a button on Android.

I don't know where should I begin. Any hints please?

**EDIT:**
What I want is an overlaying window like the WhatsApp app when clicking the emoticon button.

Comment: do you struggle to get the overlay window, or to get hold of a button click event in the first place?

Comment: I want to get the overlay window please.

Comment: it is possible to start a new `Activity` and set the background as transparent (from within the xml file), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: In fact what I want to do is something like the WhatsApp app when clicking the emoticon button.

Comment: as far as I know, this is just a customized Activity with height, width, a transparent background color and (if I'm not totally wrong) a half transparent png image as background image. just try playing with the xml of the Activity... ;)

Comment: Please share your experiences once you've tried it ;)

Comment: @user1471575 try showing a customized android Dialog on button click, instead of creating a whole new activity.

Comment: I used a frame layout instead of using activities :)